# C/C++ output streams are not working in my Ubuntu 14.4

Tags: ubuntu, printf, stdout, cout, ostream

Ubuntu 14.4; g++/gcc 4.8.2

Here is my c++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::flush;
using std::ofstream;

#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
  ofstream oStrm("TestCpp.txt");
  FILE *pStrm;

  //
  // C++ tests
  //
  cout << "test" << endl << flush;
  cout.flush();

  oStrm << "test" << endl << flush;
  oStrm.flush();

  oStrm.close();

  //
  // C tests
  //
  printf("test! \n");

  pStrm = fopen("TestC.txt", "w");

  fprintf(pStrm, "test \n"); 

  fflush(NULL);

  fclose(pStrm);

  return 0;
}
```

I compile & link it with:
g++ -g -lm -o test main.cpp

When I run this in my debugger (nemiver v0.9.5) it works as expected:
stdOut:
test
test!

textCpp.txt:
test

textC.txt:
test

But when I run it from my bash shell, I get nothing.  No output files. No output to stdout.  I suspected stream buffering, but my various attempts at flush() & fflush() didn't help.  I must be missing something obvious.
Any ideas?

Comment: I do not know what is your problem. It runs perfectly in my ubuntu 14.04. Have you tried running using ./test after compiling and linking it with g++ -g -lm -o test main.cpp?

Comment: It runs.  It just does not produce any output.  I have "." in my PATH, so I don't need the "./".

Comment: I have partially figured it out.  Indeed, if I do "./test", it works.  It also works if I use a different executable file name:  "g++ -g -lm -o test1 main.cpp". Ubuntu has a file called /usr/bin/test that may be being called instead of my test, even though only my "./test" file is listed with "which test".  Weird.

Comment: Hahaha. Glad that it's now working on your machine. :)